# Sum variable by month/year in r

Tags: r

I receive historical demand data from an excel spreadsheet in the following format:

```
Part Number  Requested Date       Quantity
123           01/24/2013 12:53       1
122           02/07/2013 09:57       1 
122           02/14/2013 09:58       7
124           11/21/2012 12:46       1
```

[I typically provide my management charts from excel by part like this but I want to be more proficient in R---doing hundreds of these at time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKpZp.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

We can try with `as.yearmon` to create the grouping variable and then get the `sum` of 'Quantity' in `summarise`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(PartNumber, yearMon = as.yearmon(RequestedDate, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")) %>% 
   summarise(Quantity = sum(Quantity))
```

Comment: I think that would work for grouping by month year, but would it also group by part number?

Comment: @manchs07  You can add the 'PartNumber' also in the group_by statement.  (updated the post)